# Por que uma função anônima é encarada como objeto em PHP?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, tipagem

```
$f = function() {
    echo "OK";
};

echo gettype($f);
```

Retorna `Object` quando teoricamente olhando era pra retornar `function`.

-

Em **JS**:

```
var f = function() {};   
typeof f;
```

Retorna `function`.

Comment: Você tem um objeto que guarda uma função. Se você fizer $f();, vai funcionar.

Comment: Aliás, a gettype não tem retorno de `function`. Veja em: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gettype.php

Comment: Na verdade uma função anonima no PHP é Closure: Classe usada para representar funções anônimas. Ou seja, se é uma classe é do tipo `object`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Introdução

É discricionário de cada linguagem definir como organizar toda sua estrutura, ou seja, cada uma faz como achar que funciona melhor para ela. Seria possível todos os dados terem apenas um tipo, poderia ser um `object` ou outro. Mas isso fica ruim para organizar códigos mais complexos, por isso quase todas as linguagens, e todas *mainstream* tem outros tipos, até para saber mais facilmente o que fazer. Consegue imaginar como seria difícil executar operações quando não se tem nenhuma informação de tipo?

## Tipagem

Segundo a [teoria de tipos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) as linguagens de tipagem dinâmica, como são PHP e JS, só tem um tipo, mas elas possuem *tags* de tipos internas e informalmente lidamos com elas como se fossem tipos diferentes, só tenha certo que isso é formalmente errado. Vou falar do jeito que todo mundo entende.

Então alguns tipos possuem *tags* mais específicas, inclusive todo valor que tem a *tag* `Object` tem outra *tag* mais interna que diz o tipo deste `Object`, mas para efeitos de tipagem só o nível do `Object` é mostrado.

Por alguma razão quiseram separar o que é um `Object` e o que são outros tipos. Eu considero isso um erro. Mas faz sentido porque essas linguagens foram criadas sem pensar que teriam essa complexidade que elas têm hoje. Não seria mais fácil tudo ser `Object` e só ter as *tags* internas dele? Assim você poderia lidar só com as *tags* e esquecer os tipos, porque no fundo tudo é o mesmo.

Pois bem, não fizeram assim e decidiram que alguns tipos de dados fossem no mesmo nível que `Object`. Isso não é exclusivo dessas duas linguagens, de forma geral todas as linguagens de tipagem dinâmica são assim. As linguagens de tipagem estática colocam tudo no mesmo nível até porque elas não usam *tags* de tipos, e sim são tipos mesmo. Infelizmente elas erram em não ter um tipo comum único, como C# tem, esta acertou. Até Java cometeu esse erro.

## Motivação

JavaScript considerou que uma função era tão importante para ela que merecia ter um tipo isolado, assim como tem `String,` Number`,` Array`, etc. No fundo todos eles são de alguma forma um objeto.

PHP não achou isso tão importante. Como esse mecanismo foi criado posteriormente pode até ter alguma questão de compatibilidade, mas só estou especulando, acredito que nem tenha esse tipo de problema. E é o que eu falo, PHP não foi criada e não é evoluída por pessoas quem entendem muito os conceitos computacionais. As pessoas não gostam de ouvir isso, mas é um fato até mesmo declarado pelo criador. Então eles criaram uma sintaxe nova para função anônima, portanto consideram importante, mas não suficiente para *tiparem* isso de forma especial. Não parece desequilibrado?

Mas não tem nada que obrigue retornar um tipo mais específico.

## Como obter o quer

Se realmente quer saber a *tag* do tipo `Object` você tem que usar [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php):

```
$f = function() {
    echo "OK";
};
echo get_class($f);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pFOoSX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ekqzwhle-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Typing/ClosureType.php).

Note que retorna `Closure` porque não é só uma função, é uma clausura, assim como também o é em JS. Cada um dá o nome que quiser, conceitualmente PHP está mais certo, porque em ambas isso é uma clausura e não apenas uma função.

Answer (score 8):

## Como o PHP lida com funções anônimas

No PHP, uma função anônima é um objeto do tipo [Closure](http://php.net/closure). 
A documentação da linguagem diz o seguinte sobre a classe Closure:

> Class used to represent anonymous functions.

No seu exemplo, a função em questão armazenada na variável `$f` é um objeto, pois é uma instância de Closure, por isso o resultado do teste de tipo diz que o valor em questão é um objeto e não uma função (como acontece no caso do Javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Porque não existe tipo de dado "function". A função [gettype()](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gettype.php) no php retorna o tipo da variável. Os tipos de dados de retorno da função gettype são:

- "boolean"
- "integer"
- "double" (por razões históricas "double" é é retornado no caso de float, e não simplesmente "float")
- "string"
- "array"
- "object"
- "resource"
- "NULL"
- "unknown type"

A sua função está como uma [função anônima](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.anonymous.php), uma closure. Uma [closure](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.closure.php) tem retorno de objetos deste tipo. Se você der um var_dump em sua variável f era irá retornar: `object(Closure)#1 (0) { }` . Também pode validar que ele é um objeto deste jeito `var_dump(is_object($f));` ele irá retornar TRUE, pois é um objeto. Também deste jeito informando que é uma closure `echo get_class($f);`.